# Compass sprites: applying individual styles to every sprite class without writing out each sprite name manually

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm [magic-importing](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) my sprites:

```
// Creating a concatenated sprite image out of all sprites in the "/images/sprites/" folder
$sprites-layout:  vertical
@import           sprites/*.png

$sprites-sprite-dimensions: true  // Image width and height will be applied to all sprite classes

+all-sprites-sprites      // Generate all sprite classes
```

I would like to add custom styles to every sprite. I managed to add styles common to all sprites by declaring a class **before** magic-importing (magic import seems to extend this class for every sprite):

```
.sprites-sprite                   // This code will be applied to all sprite classes
  @extend         %inline-block
```

But I would also like to apply styles individual to each sprite. E. g. I would like to use `min-width` instead of `width`.

As a temprorary solution, I list all my sprite names manually:

```
=sprite-custom-styles($item)
  +sprites-sprite($item)
  padding-left: px(sprites-sprite-width($item) * 1.3)
  min-width:    sprites-sprite-width($item)

@each $item in foo, bar, baz, quux
  .sprites-#{$item}
    +sprite-custom-styles($item)
```

This is very burdensome, I would like to do this automatically.

Maybe magic importing creates a list of names that I can use? Or maybe I could define a mixin with a certain name that magic importing would call on every sprite class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the list of names with the function `sprite-names($map)`, like that:

```
@each $item in sprite-names($sprites-sprites)
  ...
```

Compass creates the sprite map `$<map>-sprites` after importing images (`@import "<map>/*.png"`).